# Extract Relevant data to relevant columns from unordered data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in the following manner in column A of excel (cells A2, A3, A4)

1. Apple 223 12 Bags 32 Carrots 4231 2321 Doughnuts 5231 232 1321 Elephants 6232
2. Apple 3123213 Bags 412321 3213 Carrots 411 Doughnuts 621 3213 Elephants 71 2321
3. Apple 212324 Carrots 52312 Bags 42313 Elephants 512312 Doughnuts 621 32132

I need to pull this data to relevant columns A, B, C, D, E.
Have been able to come up with the below solution till now.

- Insert column headers A, B, C, D, E, Dummy in first row (i.e. B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1)
- Put the following formula into the respective cells on rows 2,3,4

  ```
   =MID($A2,FIND(E$1,$A2)+LEN(E$1),IFERROR(FIND(F$1,$A2),LEN($A2)+1)-FIND(E$1,$A2)-LEN(E$1))
  ```

This works for data set 1,2 where the data is in ordered fashion i.e. A then B then C so on

But it doesnt work on data set 3 where data is undordered i.e. A then C then B then E then D..as shown below.  Any suggestions appreciated - Am open to VBA solutions too. Thanks.

[image: TexttoCols]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your formula is too complex, for the problem as you laid it out ...

[image]

Where Cell B2 contains (filled down and across) ...

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B$1,$A2)),"",MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+2, 1))
```

This solution relies on the fact the number portion is only a single character long.

**Updated for modified requirement**

Use this formula in B2 (filled down and across) ...

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B$1,$A2)),"",MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+2, IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+2)-(FIND(B$1,$A2)+2)),LEN($A2),FIND(" ",$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+2)-(FIND(B$1,$A2)+2))))
```

... for this result ...

[image]

This solution relies on the fact there are spaces between the Column Names (A, B, etc) and the numbers, and a single character for the Column Name.

**Updated for modified requirement**

Use this formula in B2 (filled down and across) ...

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B$1,$A2)),"",MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1, IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1)-(FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1)),LEN($A2),FIND(" ",$A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1)-(FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1)+1))))
```

For this result ...

[image]

**Updated for modified requirement**

A user defined function is much simpler for this problem.

The following VBA user defined function (UDF) ...

```
Function FindData(DataString As String, SearchString As String, AllSearchStrings As Range) As String
Dim iLoop As Long, iTemp As Long, iStart As Long, iEnd As Long
Dim oCell As Range
' Initialize
    FindData = ""
    If DataString = "" Then GoTo Done
    If SearchString = "" Then GoTo Done
    If AllSearchStrings.Cells.Count = 0 Then GoTo Done

' find where in the data string the data starts
    On Error Resume Next
        iStart = WorksheetFunction.Find(SearchString, DataString, 1) + Len(SearchString) + 1
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsError(iStart) Or iStart = 0 Then GoTo Done

' find where in the data string the data ends
    iEnd = Len(DataString) + 1
    For Each oCell In AllSearchStrings
        On Error Resume Next
            iTemp = WorksheetFunction.Find(oCell.Value, DataString, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If IsError(iTemp) Then
            iTemp = Len(DataString) + 1
        Else
            If iTemp < iStart Then iTemp = Len(DataString) + 1
            If iTemp < iEnd Then iEnd = iTemp
        End If
    Next oCell

' extract the string
    FindData = Trim(Mid(DataString, iStart, iEnd - iStart))
Done:
End Function
```

... called in Cell B2 (filled down and across) ...

```
=FindData($A2,B$1,$B$1:$G$1)
```

... and gets this result ...

[image]

Comment: The given solution above does work with data of say A 22312 B 32 C 42312321 D 52312321321 E 6232. Thanks.

Comment: your answer is perfect for the question I had asked. But in my zeal to simplify the question, I left out important bits i.e 1. The column headers can be variable and 2. data values have spaces. I have clarified this in my question now. This makes the question and the prospective answer complex in my view. Thanks, but can't upvote because i dont have the rep as yet :)

Comment: @PVR - I don't see any example in your question where the data values have spaces.

Comment: I make the edit in the image but not in the initial data. Made the changes now. sorry abt that.

Comment: Works like a charm. Can't thank you enough @OldUgly. One minor error, Len(DataString) should be replaced by Len(DataString) + 1 in 3 places above to correct the last digit not coming up in the Elephants column above.

Comment: @PVR - yep - very late here. Not being too sharp. Thanks.

Comment: @PVR - updated the code. Also added a Trim statement to clean up trailing blanks.